# Ionic Local Notifications interval

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello i am trying to implement local notification
it works perfectly right and shows notification on NotificationTime
but when i add every param for daily notification,it does not show notifications
also if add minute it start showing notification every minute the moment it sets ignoring at:NotificationTime
not showing notifications for week also
my code is

title: ‘Local ILocalNotification Example’,
text: ‘Multi ILocalNotification 2’,
at: NotificationTime,
every: ‘day’

please help

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem. i just tried with every 'minute' and 'second'. it's working fine except 'day'